# common data between multiple android tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I have to display same data in two different formats in two android app tabs.The data I retrieve from cloud, so the operation is quite expensive. In one tab I want to show the data in a list formate and in another tab want to show the same data on maps. I want the data to be available to both tabs but would like to get it from the cloud once. How can I do this? I don't want to share the data of one tab with another but just want the same data available to both tabs in their onCreateView method.

Thanks

Comment: Have the data as a field in the parent Activity. Then in both Fragments you can access that data with a call to getActivity first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two fragments - one for list view and other for map view. 
So your main Activity will have the data gathered from server, which could be used by fragments simultaneously

Comment: I have MainActivity from where I create ReportsFragment and that Fragment have then both the tabs. Is it possible with this architecture or I will need to change? The data is retrieved asynchronously and I call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in a callback function.

Comment: I think you can achieve this using your current architecture. Because fragments have no onCreate and onDestroy lifecycle.

Comment: thanks Ankesh Kumar, I want to add that I need to request data from the cloud service only when the user open the ReportsFragment and not cache the data at the start. its a long data (1000s of records) and the data is requested for pagination. it takes a few seconds to get the data.

Comment: some code snippet, i request data from server. getFloodData(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
        });
       }
      });

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that  Fragments can not be used alone. Every fragment dependent an Activity.

According to this information you must have an Activity, a PagerAdapter for providing tabs and two fragments. When your activity crates(onCreate() method) you can start to retrieve data from cloud and send data to Fragments.

Note : You can use EventBus for sending datas to fragments from Activities.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus